# vb.net WebRequest Post giving 400 Bad Request when containing ampersand

Tags: xml, vb.net, post, webrequest, http-status-code-400

I'm running into an issue with WebRequest when the POST contains an ampersand.  When attempting to get the response, I am being thrown a 400 Bad Request error.  I've tried `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` on the `postData` variable, but that throws an error as well.

Here is my code:

```
Dim request As WebRequest
Dim postData As String = String.Empty
Dim byteArray As Byte()
Dim dataStream As Stream = Nothing
Dim response As WebResponse = Nothing

Dim reader As StreamReader = Nothing
Dim responseFromServer As String
request = WebRequest.Create(_strWSURL)
request.Method = "POST"
postData = "p_input_xml_doc=<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<XMLRootNode>
 <Transactions>
  <Transaction>
   <Data>FirstNode</Data>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction>
   <Data>Second&amp;Node</Data>
  </Transaction>
 </Transactions
</XMLRootNode>"

byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'"
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
dataStream.Close()
response = request.GetResponse()'<--Thorws "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: What type of service are you calling?  WCF?  Did you write it?  Did you debug it?  Have you tried using fiddler to inspect what's going over the wire?

Comment: you could add [<[[CDATA]]>] tags to the raw content of the nodes, however, i agree with @RickS in that sense that the request looks a bit odd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Comment: It was not written by me but a partner that we are working with.  Is it possible that this is an error on their end?  I assumed that since it's a bad request error, that it has something to do with the HTTP request.